# Architectural modeling and bevel

Tags: modeling

Why do architectural modelers use little or almost no bevel?
Caught my attention.What is the reason for this?

---

[image]

[image]

I came across these two on turbosquid, and what I was more curious about was the following article on turbosquid.

Holding/Support Edges

Holding/support edges present to retain shape after subdivision. This also applies to 3D text.

NOTE: For Architecture No holding edges, chamfers, micro-bevels, etc. required.

Comment: hello, do you have some examples like videos of architectural modelers? If they don't need to bevel, they won't, it depends on the shape you need to do I guess...

Comment: Sounds like an invalid presumption, mind sharing examples to illustrate? :))

Comment: In technical architecture are at least, an edge can mean a change in span direction, material, depth, etc. Most of the time in 3d modelling bevels are used to make edges more believable, as in reality there cannot exist a perfectly sharp corner on any object and the human eye expects light to bounce more or less softly on edges. In a technical drawing one can expect a perfect representation of how the different elements will be designed, independantly of how they will be constructed in reality. However I don't think it's a fair assumption to say architecture modellers never use edges.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I apologize for the assumption I made.